# Regex for sub domain

Tags: python, regex, dns, subdomain

I have a system that can generate one-level subdomains, I want a regex expression to validate the subdomain before creating it.

So far I have come up with:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

from my test cases it

- Restricts use of hyphen at start and end
- allows only letters, numbers, and hyphens
- limits the total length to 63

I still am not sure if my pattern is correct. If someone can give me a better regex or point out any rule that I forgot about, please let me know.

Comment: Is there a minimum length? What programming language (or regex flavor) are you using? You say only numbers and hyphens but you have letters in your pattern. Which one of them is right?

Comment: Characters, i am not sure if someone edited it and added the word "characters" there, or u miss read it.

Comment: i am using the regex on python code

Comment: To whoever voted as opinion-based, there's nothing opinion-based about this. The OP is asking whether their solution is _sufficient_ (which it obviously isn't).

Comment: i mean letters, as domain names cant have special characters, leme edit that. thankyou

Comment: Anyway, you probably want to use something like `^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9].{62}$)[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$`.

Comment: thankyou very much for the regex, can you also please tell me what other rules does this regex cover

Comment: *"I still am not sure if my pattern is correct."* have you... tested it?

Comment: @TylerH obviously i have tested it, but i could have still missed something, as this would go into my dns record and i dont wana take chances?

Comment: @ZOthix You should compare your test suite against the documentation of whatever authoritative DNS source you're using. Then when you pass your test suite you are not left with wondering whether it is "correct"... you know it is. It also seems like you haven't actually tested it, since as the answer below points out, one of your test cases would fail (limits the total length to 63).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your pattern:

1. Using the `+` quantifier after the first character class allows for infinitely long strings (the `{0,61}` quantifier becomes redundant).
2. Using the `*` quantifier after the last character class allows it to match zero chars (which makes the pattern accept a hyphen at the end) and also has the same problem as above.

You may use:

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9].{0,62}$)[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LaZYLb/1)**.

**Breakdown:**

- `^` - Beginning of the string.
- `(?=` - Start of a positive [Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - The first character must be alphanumeric only.
  - `.{0,62}` - Followed by up to 62 characters.
  - `$` - Then, the end of the string.
- `)` - End of the Lookahead.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*` - Match 0 or more alphanumeric characters or hyphens.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]$` - Match one alphanumeric character at the end of the string.

If you need to set a minimum length, just change `{0,62}` to `{n,62}` where `n+1` is the minimum length. Or you could get rid of the Lookahead (as long as the minimum length is >= 2) and use:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

...replacing `{0,61}` with `{n,61}` where `n+2` is the minimum length.

Comment: this expects me to have full 63 characters, how i think it should be is {0,62} so user is able to create 0-63 letter domain

Comment: The Lookahead checks for one alphanumeric character + up to 62 other characters, so the total is up to 63.

Comment: There are still edge cases not handled, like IDNs starting with `xn--` (but you can't have any other prefix, so `bq--` is invalid).

Comment: Also the whole name can not be bigger than 253 bytes in practice.

Comment: if you could give a better solution i would be thankful ❣️